# How to render an auto layout view controller to a bitmap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, autolayout

**TL;DR**: Is there a way know within a UIView derivative class when itself and its children have been laid out?

**Long version**: I have a parent view (A) and a hierarchy of views within it. It is a custom control. All subviews of A are laid out using Auto Layout in `updateConstraints`. I want to take a snapshot of A once everything is laid out (possibly form within the A's code).

Laying out subviews using auto layout gives great freedom. The child views are simple UIViews that render to black and parent view is white. Once the layout is complete, I take the snapshot of the view and set it as a mask layer (for other magical stuff) and remove all the child views. So far, I have gotten it to work from within a ViewController and using `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews` you can override `UIView.layoutSubviews`, call super and then take the snapshot of your view.

Comment: Thanks. It never occurred to me and works fine for my case.